# How to make pg-promise use peer authentication?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I'm using pg-promise in a typescript express app.
I can log on to psql by just typing psql because the linux username is the same as the database name and I'm set to use peer authentication.

I can't seem to get pg-promise to let me do this - it always fails and gives an error that password authentication failed.

I've been looking at the pgpromise docs but can't find anything - I've tried all sorts of connection strings.

Comment: [What exactly have you tried?](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax) Sounds like the server configuration error, not the library issue.

Comment: hi @vitaly-t - thanks for responding - I tried leaving the fields blank when using a connection object, and a connection string without username and password. however, I've just had success with using a socket:/ connection in a connection string, instead of a postgres:/ one (I believe a TCP connection?) I will write up an answer in case it helps anyone else

Comment: @vitaly-t Why would this be a server config problem if psql can use peer authentication just fine?

Comment: @Bergi NodeJS client for Postgres needs a bit more than what psql uses. It's a typical issue of psql being able to access the server, but your NodeJS client can't. Plenty of questions about it on StackOverflow.

Comment: What exactly does it need?

It should be possible to connect with nothing but a path to the socket and your actual identity ( unix login ), which the database can verify.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work for me by using a [Unix Domain Socket](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-connection-string/#user-content-connection-strings) instead of a TCP socket and connecting using a connection string.

So my connection looks like this `const db = pgp('socket:/var/run/postgresql');` but presumably the `/var/run/postgresql` could vary by system.

Comment: I believe what you published here, is not a solution, rather a work-around to your server configuration problem. I suggest you look into that, how to configure server authentication right.

Comment: thanks @vitaly-t I'm not sure what the config problem is - it's set up to use peer auth and does so outside of pg-promise. getting it sorted is on my to do list, but for now I've got it working :)